# Getting Applied Energistics 1 mod for 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I have been looking everywhere for a Applied Energistics 1 mod for minecraft 1.7.10 but cannot find any? I have only found Applied Energistics 2 And I really want the first mod for 1.7.10 cause it is better to use. Is there someone out there who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The [official website](http://ae1.ae-mod.info/Downloads/) does not mention a 1.7 version of the mod, and that's final. Unless someone ported the mod to 1.7 *illegally* (it's not open source), there's no way to play the mod in 1.7.

That's because the author of the mod decided to use the version jump to re-write large portions of the mod and release it as Applied Energistics 2.